# How to solve the values of a tree diagram?

Tags: probability, game-theory, trees

So i have this question:[image]

and this in the answer on the answer sheet:

[image]

By backward induction, we know that I prefers g to h since 3>2 and likewise I prefers l to i.

Now im a bit stuck in order to find p.  I know that on the right hand side I's utility is the expected value that yields 4 with probability p and yield 1 with probability 1-p.

Hence the expected utility for I is *4p+(1-p)=3p+1*. Then if i set this equal to the left hand side value of I , which is three:

3p+1=3, i get than p=2/3.

From here I am lost. How can i get the values of the answer sheet? Please explain in the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. What you have found is that for $p=2/3$ it does not matter whether $I$ chooses $a$ or $b$. But what happens if $p$ gets larger than $2/3$? In that case $3p+1>3$ and thus $I$ should choose $b$. On the other hand if $p < 2/3$ then $3p+1<3$ and thus $I$ should choose $a$ in the first move.

Now when $I$ chooses $b$ in the first move then the expected outcome for $II$ will be $2p+3(1-p)=3-p$. If $I$ chooses $a$ in the first move then the expected outcome for $II$ is $1$ because $II$ will choose $c$ over $d$.

Hence the you arrive at the solution.

Comment: Can't i do the same thing that you do for player 1 for player 2? ie. 3-p=1?

Comment: Then p=2 for player 2?

Comment: I get this part ....Now when  chooses  in the first move then the expected outcome for  will be 2+3(1−)=3−. If  chooses  in the first move then the expected outcome for  is 1 because  will choose  over . But how do i get to the answer from this^

Comment: How does the answer sheet say that if p is greater than 2/3 player 2 will choose 3-p? Why is it using the value of p from player 1?

Comment: I was thinking of equating 3-p=1. Then p=2. Then if p> 2 then 3-p>1 then II chooses b. If p<2 then 3-p<1 then II chooses a. Then what ?

Comment: To your first question: This would not make sense: The reason for comparing $3p+1$ with $3$ is because player $I$ has the power to decide whether he wants to go for the left side of the tree or for the right side. The value of $p$ however does not influence any decision for player $II$. This is because player $II$ can only make a choice when player $I$ has already decided to take $a$.

Comment: When $p > 2/3$ then we know that player $I$ will choose $b$ over $a$. Thus the expected outcome for player $II$ is $3-p$. If $p > 2/3$ then player $II$ will never get to decide anything.

Comment: Cant player II make a choice if  player 1 decides to take b?

Comment: You say that If  chooses  in the first move then the expected outcome for  is 1 because  will choose  over . Then wouldn't there be 1 as an outcome on the answee sheeet?

Comment: If player $I$ takes $b$ then we can see in the game tree that player $II$ does not get to decide but instead an outcome will be chosen randomly (based on $p$). There is a $1$ on the answer sheet. It says that the outcome is $(3, 1)$ if $p<2/3$. This means that if $p<2/3$ player $I$ will get $3$ and player $II$ will get $1$.

Comment: Thanks! could you help me on my other question that i posted which involves this game in strategic form ?